# Cast to datetime returns null only for columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime

I'm trying to cast a varchar column in MySQL with str_to_date(), the thing is that it works perfectly if you copy the string from the column, like '04/24/2015 00:00:00', but when you try it with the column itself it returns null.

This is my trial query:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('04/24/2015 00:00:00', '%m/%d/%Y %T'),
STR_TO_DATE(StartDate,'%m/%d/%Y %T'), StartDate
FROM TMP;
```

This returns:

```
2015-04-24 00:00:00  (NULL)  04/24/2015 00:00:00
```

I tried a ton of things but nothing seems to work...

This is the result with HEX(startdate):

```
2015-04-24 00:00:00 (NULL) 00300034002F00320034002F0032003000310035002000300030003A00300030003A00300030
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please add `HEX(StartDate)` to your query and edit the question to include the new result?

Comment: It's a really strange encoding issue I can't fully grasp. Your data appears to be stored as UTF-16. Is the column defined as such?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of the root issue but MySQL is interpreting your SQL code and your column data as being in different encodings and the `STR_TO_DATE()` function can't cope with that. Please see the test code:

```
SELECT 
STR_TO_DATE('04/24/2015 00:00:00', '%m/%d/%Y %T'),
STR_TO_DATE(StartDate, '%m/%d/%Y %T'),
STR_TO_DATE(CONVERT(StartDate USING utf8), '%m/%d/%Y %T'),
StartDate
FROM (
    SELECT _utf16 0x00300034002F00320034002F0032003000310035002000300030003A00300030003A00300030 AS StartDate
) TMP;
```

If you run this in a MySQL client configured for UTF-8 you get the expected result.

Comment: This worked just fine! The root of the problem seems to be the encoding of the table, because it is in utf16_spanish_ci

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine here. Dont know why yours is not working.

Sqlfiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9c2499/1/0

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think your StartDate column is in DateTime type , so when your are doing STR_TO_DATE its not working.

> Try by changing STR_TO_DATE to DATE_FORMAT

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('04/24/2015 00:00:00', '%m/%d/%Y %T'), DATE_FORMAT(StartDate,'%b %d %Y %h:%i %p'), StartDate as dt FROM TMP;
```

Hope this helps